# ObjectInputStream[Java]

Tags: java

i'm new to file i/o so i'm sorry if this is a pretty bad question.

Currently I have an add method/main method and a person class my outputstream is working fine in the add method: This is at the top of the method

```
       FileOutputStream myFile = null;
        try {
            myFile = new FileOutputStream("txt123.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(myFile);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And I then have this twice because there are two types of people that can be added

```
oos.writeObject(person);
oos.close();
System.out.println("Done");
```

So my question, how do i get the input working and finally where do i put it, in the add method or the main method, I read how to do what i done here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/

He also has a guide on reading in the objects but I cant seem to get it working

- Thanks!

Comment: "Can't seem to get it working" is not an adequate problem description. What's the question here?

Comment: @John Cody No accepted answer on this, consider my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You would be reading the file you just created like this:

```
ObjectInputStream in = 
  new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("txt123.txt"));
  // terrible file name, because this is binary data, not text

try{

   Person person = (Person) in.readObject();

finally{
   in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the ObjectOutputStream with the FileOutputStream as follows. I'm also guessing you need to place the read/write code in one place to allow re-use. Here's a simple example with the read/write in a DAO.

```
 public static class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    public Person(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static class PersonDao {
    public void write(Person person, File file) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(file));
        oos.writeObject(person);
        oos.close();
    }

    public Person read(File file) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                file));
        Person returnValue = (Person) oos.readObject();
        oos.close();
        return returnValue;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    PersonDao personDao = new PersonDao();
    Person alice = new Person("alice");
    personDao.write(alice, new File("alice.bin"));
    Person bob = new Person("bob");
    personDao.write(bob, new File("bob.bin"));

    System.out.println(personDao.read(new File("alice.bin")));
    System.out.println(personDao.read(new File("bob.bin")));
}
```